# Cubic with negative real roots — inequality on coefficients

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$ such that all roots of $x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$ are negative real numbers. If $a < 3$, prove that $b + c < 4$.

---

My attempt:

I tried first putting a as positive and seeing what happens, which didn't really lead to anything. If we put $a$ as negative, then we have 3 terms which are certainly negative, which would imply that $c$ is certainly positive.
this would also imply, that $|c| > |b|$

Now, we could say, since$ b $would be negative, that $b + c = c - |b|$. I have no idea now, how to prove that the difference between the two should be less than 4, and also how to prove that this should be true when $a$ is positive but less than 3, since the problem hasn't provided a clue on the possible roots of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $-u$, $-v$ and $-w$ be our roots.

Thus, $u$, $v$ and $w$ are positives, by the given $u+v+w<3$ and we need to prove that:
$$uv+uw+vw+uvw<4.$$
Now, let $u=tp$, $v=tq$ and $w=tr$ such that $t>0$ and $p+q+r=3.$

Thus, $$t(p+q+r)<3,$$ which gives $$0<t<1.$$
But $$uv+uw+vw+uvw=t^2(pq+pr+qr)+t^3pqr<pq+pr+qr+pqr$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$pq+pr+qr+pqr\leq4$$ or
$$\frac{(pq+pr+qr)(p+q+r)}{3}+pqr\leq\frac{4(p+q+r)^3}{27}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4p^3+3p^2q+3p^2r-10pqr)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM or by Muirhead or by very many another ways.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Michael's start, we WTS if $ u + v + w < 3$, then

$$uv+uw+vw+uvw<4.$$

This follows from:

$\sqrt[3]{uvw} \leq \frac{ u+v+w}{3} < 1 \Rightarrow uvw < 1$, and
$3 (uv + vw + wu ) \leq (u+v+w)^2 < 9 \Rightarrow uv+vw+wu < 3$.

Comment: I missed it. :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Haha, I'm glad for you to do all the heavy lifting on the hard inequality problems. I can then add the "easy" approach if I ever see one.

Comment: OK, dear  Calvin. But I think it's not always possible. :)

Comment: Oh, of course not. I wasn't implying that. I often look at your solutions and wonder how you came up with them. I'm guessing that you're using some computer software to help determine the factorizations? Either that or you've gotten really experienced with finding the right split.

Comment: In most cases I make it by hand, but sometimes I use a computer (WA, calculator).

Comment: Damn, that's impressive. I usually give up once it gets "non-obvious" how to Muirhead/CS it.